# Symfony with easyadmin, trying to display value instead of index in a dropdown from a database

Tags: php, symfony, dropdown, easyadmin

I'm working under symfony 5 with easyadmin 3 and i'm trying to create a form with a dropdown of category coming from a database, until here it works well but when i open the form, the category are displayed with their index and not with their name... in fact i've a choicefield that use an array too and it actually shows the index of the content instead of their name, I'll show you

```
#src\Repository\CategorieRepository.php
        /**
         * @return Categorie[]
         */
        public function findAll(){
            return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.titre', 'ASC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
        }
    
#src\Controller\Admin\ExerciceCrudController.php
        public function getCategBdd()
        {
            $categ = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Categorie::class);
            return $tab = array($categ->findAll());
        }
    
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
        {
            $tab = $this->getCategBdd();
      
            $fields = [
                    ChoiceField::new('main')
                    ->setLabel('Main')
                    ->setChoices(['Gaucher','Droitier'])
                    ->renderExpanded(true)
                    ->allowMultipleChoices(true),
                ChoiceField::new('categorie')
                     ->setLabel('Categorie')
                     ->renderAsNativeWidget(true)
                     ->setChoices($tab),
     ];
       
            return $fields;
        
        }
```

I've heard about entity type for doing this but I don't really understand what and how can I do something with so if someone could help me thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Entity class you're using, you want to add a `__toString()` method and return the name property.

For example

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally i've already made a tostring function that's why I don't understand why it displays the category by their index in the tab